# Are we aware that questionhub.com are 'live-scraping' SF's content?

Tags: discussion

I've just spotted that questionhub.com are scraping SF questions and answers, not from the torrented roll-ups but live from the site. Is this a good thing?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Doesn't look like they are following [rule #3](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)</strike> Asked Jeff, he sid the link was the most important part.

> Show the author names for every question and answer

They are only showing the gravitars

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing has been going on for a while:

- ["copyright" and QuestionHub harvesting questions from SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60957/copyright-and-questionhub-harvesting-questions-from-so)
- [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962#48962)

In that case I *think* question-hub is doing it right, but check for attribution to be certain.

Answer (score -3):

As for me, I think it's good, as it is good when a valuable information is spread and easy to find by a stranger.

Considering a moral aspect, I think they should link to the origin. I don't know whether they do - I haven't ever been to that site. If yes - this is probably beneficial for StackExchange community as more people come to know about StackExchange and come here sooner oy later. If they even link to authors' profiles - this can be probably even excellent.